# Returning Expression<Func<T, bool>> where T may be a few different types

Tags: c#, expression

I have to get items from table X and find them by B property

How can I do that dynamically? because I'm struggling with types so hard

I thought about something like code below
and implementing an interface for all those types User/Car/Company
that'd "point" on desired property (firstname / model / company name)

Sorry if I didnt express myself properly, I hope code'll show the problem better.

```
public IActionResult test(string type, string value)
{
    var exp = GetExpression(type, value);

    return View(GetCount(exp));
}
```

---

```
public Expression<Func<???, bool>> GetExpression(string type, value)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case "User":
        return x => x.FirstName == value;

        case "Car":
        return x => x.Model == value;   

        case "Company":
        return x => x.CompanyName == value;

        default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

```
public int GetCount(Expression<Func<???, bool>> exp, ??? Table)
{
    return _context.Table.Where(exp).Count();
}
```

---

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class Company
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

With an interface:

---

```
public interface IExpressionable
{
    public string Helper;
}
```

---

```
public class User : IExpressionable
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Helper => FirstName;
}
```

---

```
public class Car : IExpressionable
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Helper => Model;
}
```

---

```
public class Company: IExpressionable
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Helper => CompanyName ;
}
```

Comment: @marsze They do not share properties between eachother

Comment: If you use interfaces you can: public Expression<Func<IExpressionable, bool>> GetExpression(string type, value). Other solution is use dynamic: Expression<Func<dynamic, bool>> GetExpression(string type, value).

Comment: I don't know why are trying to make this so complicated. Also, you code seems wrong, look at `GetCount`, there is a table parameter, which you don't use, and you don't even pass it when you call the method.

Comment: You're conflating several different ways of going about this, and are not explaing what you actually want to achieve. Why does your title mention a generic type when your code makes no attempt at using generics? Why are you stringly typing your classes? Why are trying to force everything into a single `test` method instead of having dedicated methods for every class (`GetUsers`, `GetCars`, ...)? Why are you effectively trying to reinvent LINQ's `Count()` method? It feels like you're trying to hack a solution into existing code which is shoddily constructed and should be refactored.

Comment: Why not `x => x.Helper == value`? You already have the interface, but never use it!?

Comment: @Flater ``Why are you stringly typing your classes? `` Because that's what comes from View's form, select list. T meant "I've no idea what type I should use here". ``It feels like you're trying to hack a solution into existing code which is shoddily constructed and should be refactored`` I do not negate that, but how can I write it in "such a proper manner"? Basically User inputs text and selects table A/B/C and input text has to match property but for every table that property is different.

Comment: @Joelty, i added my answer below view it might be it help you :)

Comment: @ershoaib I see, thanks, I'm about to give it a try :)

Comment: @Joelty: `Because that's what comes from View's form` You're shifting the blame and dodging the question. I didn't ask why this particular code snippet uses the string, but rather why the string is used to begin with (whether in the view,controller or wherever). `T meant "I've no idea what type I should use here"` I'm disinclined to believe that you stumbled on using T as a placeholder without knowing about generics. `how can I write it in such a proper manner?` That question (a) goes well beyond acceptable question scope and (b) is unanswerable when you don't post the relevant code.

Comment: @Flater ``ou're shifting the blame and dodging the question. I didn't ask why this particular code snippet uses the string, but rather why the string is used to begin with (whether in the view,controller or wherever).`` Because how otherwise I would be able to do it? You're thinking about using pattern matching here? ``That question (a) goes well beyond acceptable question scope and (b) is unanswerable when you don't post the relevant code.`` So in different words: ``How can I allow user to load data from X or Y or Z table with filter (Where predicate) which is different for every table``?

Comment: It's kinda difficult to provide code to it because its just concept. Of course at the end of the day there's an ``if``-ish way

Comment: @Joelty `It's kinda difficult to provide code to it because its just concept.` Exactly my point. StackOverflow is not a code factory - nor a tutorial site. StackOverflow is here to help you with problems in existing code, specifically to prevent such abuses. For a theoretical question, go to SoftwareEngineering. For a practical question, post code to StackOverflow. Asking for code based on a theoretical wishlist is not acceptable on either site because advice can thus be exploited as free labor.

Comment: ``Asking for code based on a theoretical wishlist is not acceptable on either site because advice can thus be exploited as free labor. `` I agree, but it's not like I didnt provide anything. I gave a code that lacked of proper types/inheritance (it was solved by ershoaib) and also the other way of solving it via interface (which was extended/completed by Michal B.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) One way to achieve your goal is

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

2) Create a one generic method to get count from  database like

```
public int GetCountFromDB<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> exp) where TEntity : class
{
    return _context.Set<TEntity>().Where(exp).Count();
}
```

3) Create one another method to determine which entity should be pass to above generic method.

```
public int? GetCount(string type, string value)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case "User":
            return GetCountFromDB<User>(x => x.FirstName == value);

        case "Car":
            return GetCountFromDB<Car>(x => x.Model == value);

        case "Company":
            return GetCountFromDB<Company>(x => x.CompanyName == value);

        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

4) And then you can use above method in your action method like

```
public IActionResult test(string type, string value)
{
    int? count = GetCount(type, value);
    return View(count);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
public class User : IHasKey
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Key => FirstName;
}

public class Car : IHasKey
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Key => Model;
}

public class Company : IHasKey
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Key => CompanyName;
}

public interface IHasKey
{
    string Key { get; }
}

public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<IHasKey> GetByKey<T>(string value) where T: class, IHasKey
    {
        return this.Set<T>().Where(obj => obj.Key == value);
    }
}
```

It can be used the following way:

```
db.GetByKey<Car>("BMW");
db.GetByKey<Company>("Microsoft");
```

Comment: I agree with the answer, but "key" is a poorly chosen name here - it implies a unique identifier. People's first names and car's models are by no means unique and the naming is confusing.

Comment: @Flater, I agree. I was actually thinking about the correct name and after 10s "key" popped in my mind. I thought it wasn't worth my time thinking about it more. Now I think that "Name" could be a better property name and IHasName would be the interface. I will keep the answer as is though and let the original poster change it if they want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to mix these:

```
_context.Users.Where(x => x.FirstName == value).Count();
_context.Cars.Where(x => x.Model == value).Count();
_context.Companies.Where(x => x.CompanyName == value).Count();
```

to:

```
_context.Table.Where(exp).Count();
// or
_context.Table.Count(exp);
```

I recommend you not to do that. It makes your code as hard as read. Because:

- `_context.Table`: which table?
- `Where(exp)` or `Count(exp)`: why we need to convert `type` to `FirstName`, `Model` or `CompanyName` inside the `exp`? We have another way to assign to.

Comment: `.Where(...).Count()` (in all your mentioned cases) can be changed to `.Count(...)`

Comment: @Flater Thanks for the tip!